# Iterate over tuples in python and compare them with constraints

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples such as this one:

```
myList = [(0, 0, 0, 0),
          (0, 0, 0, 1),
          (0, 0, 1, 0),
          (0, 1, 0, 0),
          (0, 1, 0, 1), 
          (1, 0, 1, 0), 
          (1, 0, 1, 1), 
          (1, 1, 0, 1), 
          (1, 1, 1, 0), 
          (1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

I want to iterate over the tuples and compare each tuple with every other tuple and return true if the first element changed and at most one other element did too; return false otherwise.

For example:

```
cmp((0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)) -> false, the first element did not change  
cmp((0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0)) -> true, the first element changed  
cmp((0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0)) -> true, the first element and only one other changed  
cmp((0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 0)) -> false, too many elements changed
```

edit: I solved thanks to heyu91
The final code I used looks like this

```
G=Graph()
G.add_vertices(myList)
for x in myList:
    for y in myList:
        if x!=y and (x[0]!=y[0]) and (sum((x[1]!=y[1], x[2]!=y[2], x[3]!=y[3]))<=1):
            G.add_edge(x,y)
```

Comment: "*return* true"?? that verb doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: To expand on @KarolyHorvath’s comment, it sounds like you want to do two separate things: (1) iterate over all pairs; (2) call a function that compares two tuples and returns a boolean. Yes?

Comment: It's better if you show the code you have so far. It's not entirely clear what the purpose is. Are you trying to find duplicate tuples in a list?

Comment: One approach would be to use [`scipy.spatial.distance.hamming`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.hamming.html) to find the number of differing tuple entries and additionaly check if the first entry differs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the format of output, so I return a list of tuples like below:

`[(x, y, (x[0]!=y[0]) and (sum((x[1]!=y[1], x[2]!=y[2], x[3]!=y[3]))<=1)) \
for x in myList \
for y in myList \
if x!=y]`

returns:

```
[((0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), False),
 ((0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), False),
 ((0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), False),
 ((0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), False),
 ((0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0), True),
 ((0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1), False),
 ((0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), False),
 ((0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 0), False),
 ((0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1), False),
 ((0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0), False),
 ((0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), False),
 ((0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), False),
 ((0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), False),
 ((0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), False),
 ((0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1), True),
 ((0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0, 1), True),
 ((0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), False),
 ((0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1), False),
 ((0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), False),
 ((0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), False),
 ((0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), False),
 ((0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), False),
 ((0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0), True),
 ((0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1), True),
 ((0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), False),
 ((0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 0), True),
 ((0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1), False),
 ((0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), False),
 ((0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), False),
 ((0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), False),
 ((0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), False),
 ((0, 1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0), False),
 ((0, 1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1), False),
 ((0, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), True),
 ((0, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 0), True),
 ((0, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1), False),
 ((0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0), False),
 ((0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 1), False),
 ((0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), False),
 ((0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), False),
 ((0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), False),
 ((0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1), False),
 ((0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0, 1), True),
 ((0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), False),
 ((0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1), True),
 ((1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), True),
 ((1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), False),
 ((1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), True),
 ((1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), False),
 ((1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), False),
 ((1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1), False),
 ((1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), False),
 ((1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 0), False),
 ((1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1), False),
 ((1, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0), False),
 ((1, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0, 1), True),
 ((1, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), True),
 ((1, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), False),
 ((1, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), False),
 ((1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), False),
 ((1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 1), False),
 ((1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), False),
 ((1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1), False),
 ((1, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0), False),
 ((1, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 1), True),
 ((1, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), False),
 ((1, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), True),
 ((1, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), True),
 ((1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), False),
 ((1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1), False),
 ((1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), False),
 ((1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1), False),
 ((1, 1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), False),
 ((1, 1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), False),
 ((1, 1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), True),
 ((1, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), True),
 ((1, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), False),
 ((1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0), False),
 ((1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1), False),
 ((1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), False),
 ((1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1), False),
 ((1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0), False),
 ((1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0, 1), False),
 ((1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), False),
 ((1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), False),
 ((1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), True),
 ((1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), False),
 ((1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1), False),
 ((1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 1), False),
 ((1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), False)]
```

Comment: Hi this is great, for some reason I hadn't come up with a simple way to do this part"(sum((x[1]!=y[1], x[2]!=y[2], x[3]!=y[3]))<=1)".

Comment: maybe `(sum(x[i]!=y[i] for i in range(1, len(x)))<=1)` is a more general way.